# Behaviour of local_variables - can anybody explain?

Tags: ruby

just curious why I cann't remove declared local variable from 'local_variables' array.

Example:

```
x=1
myarr = local_variables.clone
p local_variables
=> [:x, :_]
p myarr
=> [:x, :_]
p local_variables.class
=> Array
p myarr.class
=> Array
myarr.delete :x
p myarr
=> [:_]
local_variables.delete :x
p local_variables
=> [:x, :_]
```

WTF ?

I did suspected calling local_variables.delete with parameter :x reinserts it back as it is declared anew. But if called with other previously undeclared symbol does not change it:

```
p local_variables
=> [:x, :_]
local_variables.delete :whatever
p local_variables
=> [:x, :_]
```

Can somebody explain ?

Thx.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the following method:

```
def foo
  [42, 23, 13]
end

foo #=> [42, 23, 13]
foo.delete 23
foo #=> [42, 23, 13]
```

Does that behaviour surprise you?

Every time you call `local_variables` (or `foo`) a new array is created. If you modify that new array that has no effect on what will happen if you call `local_variables` again.

Comment: I see, it is just a method returning an Array instance. THAT'S an explanation. Thank you.

Comment: It only lefts a question how to programmaticaly determine at runtime if a symbol is a variable or a method. Is has to be possible because Ruby interpreter has to know how to handle it.

Comment: @David: `local_variables.include?(symbol)`

Comment: @sepp2k: Thanks. But what about 'local_variables' symbol ? How can I recognize it is a method ? Should I test local_variables, global_variables arrays and if it is not here it is a probably a symbol for a method ? Btw. 'local_variables' is a method of Kernel module but I've had to check return value of Kernel.methods call. Is there some more simple way I may have missed ?

Comment: @David: Add parentheses to the `local_variables` call. `local_variables().include?(symbol)` works even if `symbol = :local_variables`. Example: `local_variables().include?(:local_variables) #=> false`, but `local_variables = 42; local_variables().include?(:local_variables) #=> true`

Comment: @sepp2k: Indeed, but I intended to discover what the original 'local_variables' symbol is. The local_variables.class did returned Array class type but it was its returning value and tells nothing about local_variables is a method. Looking for something like is_a_method() call.

Comment: @David: If it's not a local variable, it's a method. Statically you can see this by seeing that there's no `local_variables = ...` anywhere in the current scope. Programmatically you can see this by seeing that `local_variables` does not appear in the array returned by `local_variables()`.

Comment: @sepp2k: And global variables always start with $ sign and constatns with an upcase character so there is no ambiguity. Thx for clarification. Ruby is far more different from Python then I did expected. Learning goes on :-)

Comment: @David Unric: `defined? local_variables #=> "method"`

Answer (score 5):

`local_variables` returns an array containing the names of all currently declared local variables. You can do anything you want with that array, but this is obviously not going to affect which local variables are declared. Why would it? If you strike out a name from phone book, does that person die?

Comment: Allright, it holds local variable names only. But why the hell .delete method does not work like at other Array class instances ? That was the point of my question.

Comment: @David Unric: What do you mean by "`.delete` method does not work like at other `Array` class instances?" I don't see how it does. `Array#delete` deletes an object from an array, which is exactly what it does here. You don't store a reference to that array, so you will *never* be able to actually *verify* that it has been deleted, but it still was. (Actually, you could use `ObjectSpace.each_object(Array)` to find the array and verify it this way, or you could just assign it to a variable.)

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK it's not possible to remove variables:

http://programming.itags.org/ruby/64695/

Comment: That's strange and sounds a bit uncosistent. Why it does behave differently although both are instaces of the same Array class ?